# Is it possible to change the default browser/engine for Android's Web View?

Tags: android, webview

So i have an HTML5 App apk that uses webview to load HTML5 / JS gui etc.

The GUI response is sooo slow. I've done research and found that this is because of the sucky web view engine of android. Also found that using CROSSWALK instead makes HTML5 /JS apps really smooth because it uses a different webview engine (chrome i thinK)..

But I already have a good native apk loading my HTML5 GUI so i wanted to stick w/ it instead of redoing the app in crosswalk shell.

So i wondered if it was possible to just set the android (via root/xpose) somehow to use a different browser engine for web view?

I'm a bit lost/noob at this so, I hope i'm making sense

Comment: Can you not just embed the crosswalk webview in the app as it stands? Instructions for replacing the webview are here: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html

Comment: Also, if you're running on KitKat+ I believe the default webview is using the Chrome rendering engine anyway. If the performance is still slow on this there may be other ways to improve performance, such as using CSS-Transitions rather than javascript animations. A few libraries will take JS animations and run them as css-transitions, I think.

Comment: Embedding the Crosswalk webview is alright but it requires a lot of changes to my App code (where HTML/JS calls native JAVA Functions already developed, and is already working w/ the default webview)